# GWT Super dev mode: full recompile when modifying DTOs

Tags: java, gwt, compilation, gwt-super-dev-mode

We are currently using GWT 2.7 and super dev mode with the incremental compilation with great success so far.
However everytime we had add a function, remove a field from a DTO (shared between server and client), a full recompile (about 20 minutes) is triggered. It is greatly hindering our productivity.

We do use the gilead library that was previously used to be able to transfer hibernate data model to the client.

I am wondering how does the incremental compilation works in super dev mode and what conditions trigger a full recompile ?